# Click on link not opening in new window

Tags: jquery, html

PLease check the link here at http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/discovery_2014.do

Please fine "I agree to the terms and conditions". When I click on **terms and conditions**, it does not open in new window.. ANy idea why?

The problem was that label had a tag inside it. For some weird reasons, it was blocking it. The answer below did helped me to figure out the problem.

Comment: what is the **target** attribute of href?

Comment: can you post the relevant code here?

Comment: You have target="_new" there, but the pdf document wouldn't open. Is the Document available?

Comment: Now its working yaar....Y again we want to work on that?

Comment: there is no link and it is a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try taking the anchor tag outside the label tag. it will work fine. the label tag's for attribute is blocking the new window. example:

```
<label>text</label><a href='url'>terms & condit..</a>
```

Comment: Yeep I did as you asked. I wonder why does the label tag block a tag inside it? Cant I put a tag inside label tag?

Comment: i suppose its not label tag that blocks, but the "for" attribute which has a click functionality by-default in the browser. you can just remove the "for" attribute and try with the label.

Comment: Actually it is working now . I have put a span around the link and added a jquery click on it. Thanks